# How to make systemd service that is started with delay and "restable" after that time

Tags: systemd, boot

I have following myService.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Application
Wants=myService.timer

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/rob/myApp
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
```

and following myService.timer that should start it after desired time:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyService Timer
PartOf=myService.service
Requires=myService.service

[Timer]
Unit=myService.service
OnBootSec=100

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

The problem is that the service starts immediately after system (Ubuntu 18) starts. When I remove "Restart=" from the .service file, timer works i.e. it starts myService after desired time, but then systemd doesn't restart myService in case of crash...
What am I missing here?

Comment: Ok, for anyone who is interested. Above configuration works fine. However myService was part of other service (this was not shown in the example). Because of that dependency myService was started immediately after system startup.